# Extracting values from tuples using nested for loop

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and taking a course on it. We were asked to take this tuple:

```
 students = [
      ('Anderson', 'Brian', 'junior', 123, ('FIN 365', 'MATH 223', 'CS 410')),
      ('Brown', 'Charlie', 'sophomore', 456, ('FIN 365', 'ECON 101')),
      ('Van Pelt', 'Lucy', 'junior', 789, ('FIN 365', 'MED 300', 'NUT 150', 'MED 330'))
    ]
```

and use a nested for loop in order to print this output:

```
Brian Anderson is a junior with ID=123 studying these classes:
  FIN 365
  MATH 223
  CS 410
Charlie Brown is a sophomore with ID=456 studying these classes:
  FIN 365
  ECON 101
Lucy Van Pelt is a junior with ID=789 studying these classes:
  FIN 365
  MED 300
  NUT 150
  MED 330
```

I was able to get the first line of each tuple just fine using this code (I know it's sloppy):

```
for row in students:
    print(f'{row[1] +  " " + row[0] + " is a " + row[2] + " with ID="} {row[3]} studying these classes: ')
```

But I can't figure out how to list out the classes now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look into something like this: `for i in row[4]: …`.  That should get you started. `row[4]` is an iterable, so a `for` loop will work with its elements.

Comment: Additionally, `+` is not needed with f-strings.  Do a bit more research on their syntax, and that’ll help clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use *tuple unpacking* to give names to the different elements. This is nicer than using indices (e.g. `row[0]`, `row[1]`). This can be done directly inside the `for`.
- Using f-strings is great, but it looks weird when you still build up the total `str` via `+`. Try to just write the whole thing in one go, no `+`.
- The final element (below called `classes`) is a `tuple` as well, so this can also be iterated over using `for`.

Below I do all of the above:

```py
students = [
    ('Anderson', 'Brian', 'junior', 123, ('FIN 365', 'MATH 223', 'CS 410')),
    ('Brown', 'Charlie', 'sophomore', 456, ('FIN 365', 'ECON 101')),
    ('Van Pelt', 'Lucy', 'junior', 789, ('FIN 365', 'MED 300', 'NUT 150', 'MED 330'))
]

for last, first, title, ID, classes in students:
    print(f'{first} {last} is a {title} with ID={ID} studying these classes:')
    for c in classes:
        print(f'  {c}')
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes a lot of sense. I've come to realize I overthink Python a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  A "nested `for` loop" is just a `for` loop inside another `for` loop, so just do the same thing for `row[4]` (the tuple of courses) that you did for the `students` list:

```
for last, first, year, num, courses in students:
    print(f"{first} {last} is a {year} with ID={num} studying these classes:")
    for course in courses:
        print(f"  {course}")
```

Note the use of tuple destructuring to clean up all the `row[n]` stuff!  If you were writing this by subscripting the tuples it'd look more like:

```
for row in students:
    print(f"{row[1]} {row[0]} is a {row[2]} with ID={row[3]} studying these classes:")
    for course in row[4]:
        print(f"  {course}")
```

Comment: Tuple unpacking?  ‘Destructuring’ is one I’ve not heard before.  :-)

Comment: Yup, same thing.  https://blog.teclado.com/destructuring-in-python/

Comment: Ya, just did a quick inet search and found it loads.  Learn something new every day!